# Corrupt jars from Spring Web MVC maven dependency

Tags: spring, maven

Recently, I came across an instance in which Spring Web MVC maven dependency intermittently downloads corrupt jars. The following was the dependency along with its version I was using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When searching further, I found that I was not the only person to experience such an issue. For example, posts in several forums suggest that this dependency seems to intermittently provide corrupt jars.

http://crunchify.com/cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file-how-to-fix-maven-build-path-error-with-corrupted-jar-file/

What is the root cause for this problem? Is cleaning the m2 repo and running fresh builds the only solution to this  issue, as suggested mostly?

Comment: Try configuring Maven to download jars from a different repository. It's probably the place you are getting them from that is broken.

Comment: I have experienced similar in the past, but it is incredibly rare. The simplest thing to do is delete your local repo and rebuild, or if you're using nexus delete the offending libs from there and rebuild. I've never seen it fail twice.

Comment: I came across an earlier commit of the project I am checking on for this issue and they have already removed a repository http://maven.springframework.org/release/ for spring-framework releases and some other spring repositories due to the intermittent occurrence of the above discussed issue. But it still persists. Is there another repository which we can use for this?

Comment: Pardon me for a mistake in the above comment. It has to be noted that the above explicitly mentioned spring repositories were removed in another pom which like in this case discussed was downloading spring artifacts. But they had encountered the same issue when they were downloading from the http://maven.springframework.org/release/ repository which actually contains this artifact.